# BizTalk Database Lookup functoid fixed condition

Tags: dictionary, mapping, biztalk

Is there a way to further restrict the lookup performed by a database lookup functoid to include another column?

I have a table containing four columns.

Id (identity not important for this)
MapId int
Ident1 varchar
Ident2 varchar

I'm trying to get Ident2 for a match on Ident1 but wish it to only lookup where MapId = 1.

The functoid only allows the four inputs any ideas?

**UPDATE**

It appears there is a technique if you are interested in searching across columns that are string data types. For those interested I found this out here...

[Google Books: BizTalk 2006 Recipes](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=tvzUW4pnoDwC&pg=PA80&lpg=PA80&dq=Advanced+Database+Lookup+Functoid+Usage&source=bl&ots=KLSJjDq45g&sig=1CfI_SZ2SxX7TnZXx-2ZazUn5n4&hl=en&ei=hW4vSpzxDYKZjAfItcmNCw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1#PPA75,M1)

Seeing as I wish to restrict on a numberic column this doesn't work for me. If anyone has any ideas I'd appreciate it. Otherwwise I may need to think about my MapId column becoming a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the MapId to MapCode of type char(3) and used the technique described in the book I linked to in the update to the original question.

The only issue I faced was that my column collations where not in line so I was getting an error from the SQL when they where concatenated in the statement generated by the map.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM IdentMap WHERE MapCode+Ident1= @P1',N'@P1 nvarchar(17)',N'<MapCode><Ident2>'
```

*Sniffed this using the SQL Profiler*